# Scale Bitmap up and keep aspect ratio

Tags: android, bitmap

I'd like to be able to scale a Bitmap up and keep the aspect ratio the same.

I don't need to set any of the dimensions to a certain size,
I know inSampleSize doesn't work for negative numbers, I'd like
something that works like that if it did.

I tried using BitmapFactory.Options(): inScaled, inTargetDensity and inDensity
but the size stayed the same.  I must not have been using them right.

I'd like to scale it up to 1X or 2X,  and I can get whatever the
width and height of the results are.  I'd really like it somewhere
around 1.5X, not quite doubled in size.

Thanks!

Comment: `scale it up to 1X` means no scaling at all... look at this sample: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you are decoding a bitmap you downscale so you don't run into OOM. The inSampleSize requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

If you are trying get the bitmap to cover the entire view you can set the scaleType of the imageView to decide how you want to scale it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Here is a link on how to load bitmaps in case you need it:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

After looking all over for some code examples
and trying some things, this worked out pretty well:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(1.5f, 1.5f);

iWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
iHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    bitmap, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, matrix, false);
```

Then I used 'resizedBitmap' in my onDraw():

```
canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap,
    scrollRect,
    displayRect,
    null);
```